# Change resource dictionary in a blazor component

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I created pages in Blazor where I manage the language change with Localization. Each page has a unique source dictionary. I inject the dictionaries with this code : @inject IStringLocalizer Localizer.

Since part of the design is the same, I would like to create a component, but no matter what I have tried, I cannot make it.

How can it be solved that the value can always be changed dynamically? Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Razor page:

```
<MyComponent ResourceName="Login"></MyComponent>

@code {
[Parameter]
public string ResourceName {get; set; }
}
```

This is my code in the component:

```
[Inject]
public IStringLocalizerFactory LocalizerFactory { get; set; }

private IStringLocalizer Localizer { get; set; }

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    Localizer = LocalizerFactory.Create<ResourceDictionary>(ResourceName);
}
```

The error message is most of the time: "The non-generic method 'IStringLocalizerFactory.Create(Type) cannot be used with type arguments", or after some changes "cannot convert from System.Type to string

Comment: You can use `Create(Type type)` or `Create(string baseName, string location)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does your program.cs look like?

```
builder.Services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
```

With this option all my resources are in the folder `Resources` this folder has the same sub structure as the root directory.

- Pages
  -- Component.razor
- Resources
  -- Pages
  --- Component.en-US.resx

Now you can use `[Inject] private IStringLocalizer<Component> L { get; set; } = default!;` in your Component.razor.cs